# Integer addition program with haskell

Tags: haskell, haskell-platform

First there is an integer(t) that indicates the number of test case.
Then 2*t lines follow. In each line there is a integer. We have to output the sum of each two numbers.

sample input:

```
3
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

sample output:

```
3
7
11
```

Comment: Is this homework? You should add the homework tag.  What have you *tried* to accomplish this in haskell? Where are you stymied?

Comment: no. I only know C,C++ and java.
i want to be familiar with Haskell.

Comment: What is the process to run a loop to take `n` numbers and print them in different lines?

Comment: @john Have you made any attempt to learn Haskell? Have you read a tutorial, e.g. [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/chapters) or [Haskell Fast & Hard](https://www.fpcomplete.com/user/yogsototh/haskell-fast-hard)?

Comment: @rampion The powers that be have banned the homework tag (they felt it was passive-aggressive and that nobody was looking for homework questions).

Comment: yes. but I need some similar code so that i can compare them to learn easily.

Comment: @john Do you have to read from a file, or will the user enter the numbers at the command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import Control.Monad (replicateM)

main :: IO ()
main = mapM_ print . map (uncurry (+)) =<< flip replicateM readIntPair =<< readLn

readIntPair :: IO (Integer, Integer)
readIntPair = do
    x <- readLn
    y <- readLn
    return (x, y)
```

`replicateM` is from [Control.Monad](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Control-Monad.html), the other functions are imported automatically from the [Prelude](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Prelude.html).

You will also want to read part of a tutorial that explains do notation: it looks the same as, but is subtly different from, a list of instructions in an imperative language.

Comment: Oh! got it. 
by the way, since haskell has no restriction in using integers(in c/c++ it is limited to 64 bit) how can i modify this code to run
 this for BigInteger

Comment: @john I've edited the code. For the most part I just replaced `Int`s in the types with `Integer`s. The complication is that `replicateM` takes an `Int` to specify how many times to perform the action, so that had to remain as an `Int` and could not be changed to an `Integer`.

Comment: It's concise, but I'm not convinced that it's the most pedagogical code ever!